# How do I perform multiple statistical tests in R (ie. two sided t test) on large data imported from .csv?

Tags: r, statistics

Trying to perform a ttest on data imported using csv.

The data looks like this:

[image: sheet containing data]

With values for "normal" cases and "cancer" cases for 99 genes.

How might I set up code to statistically compare "normal" and "cancer" values (n=20 for each cateogry)
for each column separately?

This would be a two sided t test, so the results would show:
Statistical difference between normal and cancer values in gene1, gene2..... gene 99.

I am hoping to avoid finding mean, sd, etc for each individual column and looking to perform these tests on my data en masse.

Comment: Have you explored the t.test function in the stats package? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/t.test

Comment: Welcome to SO, hartmanz! It's not clear if you understand the theory of t-tests and don't know how to use [`t.test`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/t.test.html), or if you have a theoretical question about the notion of statistical tests. Can you clarify? Also, please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Answer (score 0):

I once wrote a function in base R to do this. The function is on github.

```
 remotes::install_github('oonyambu/SLR')
 SLR::multiple_tests(. ~ category, df)
```

eg `t.test` for `iris` dataset:

```
 SLR::multiple_tests(.~Species, iris)
```

Note that all the levels present in the factor must be represented. Otherwise the code will throw an error of `not enough 'y' observations`

eg:

```
 SLR::multiple_tests(.~Species, iris[1:100,]) # error
```

This is because the factor `Species` contains a level that has no data. The best case is to convert the factor into character thereby removing the missing levels:

```
 SLR::multiple_tests(.~Species, transform(iris[1:100,], Species = as.character(Species)))
```