# How do I iterate a command over many columns of a data frame in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a command:

```
t.test(df$gene1[1:20],df$gene1[21:40],alternative=c("two.sided"))
```

Which returns two-sided t-test between two groups in the column "gene1" in my data frame:
Group 1: Values in rows 1-20
Group 2: values in rows 21-40.

I would like to iterate this command over 99 columns to return p-value for the t test for two groups in gene 1-99.

How would I go about doing this?

Is there a better command to return the two-sided t test for speciifc values in a single column, which does not include specific names of columns?

I've tried:

```
lapply(df[-1], function(x) t.test(df$gene1[1:20],df$gene1[21:40],alternative=c("two.sided")))
```

Which returns 99 t-tests but they're obviously all testing the same column: gene1.

Comment: Isn't https://stackoverflow.com/a/78035635/3358272 (on your previous question) what you need? BTW, we still can't do anything without sample data. Please [edit] your question and add the output from `dput(x)` to a [code block].

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48907955/6356278

Comment: BTW, you loop over `df[,-1]`, each column is seen in the inner-function as `x`, yet you still reference `df$gene1`, try `lapply(df[,-1], function(x) t.test(x[1:20], x[21:40], alternative=c("two.sided")))`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `lapply` is working over each column but you're ignoring the column data. You say `function(x)`, so *use `x`*.

```r
lapply(df[-1], function(x) t.test(x[1:20], x[21:40], alternative="two.sided"))
```